# headless volcite with biblatex-chicago

Tags: citing, biblatex-chicago

In `biblatex-chicago`, I would like a command like `\headlesscite` except for citing multivolume works (normally done with `\volcite`), which could be called `\headlessvolcite`. Does such a cite command exist? I couldn't seem to find what it would be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make new `\volcite` commands by calling `\volcitecmd` or `\multivolcitecmd` before the `\cite` command.

e.g.,

```
\newrobustcmd*{\headlessvolcite}{\volcitecmd\headlesscite}
\newrobustcmd*{\headlessvolcites}{\multivolcitecmd\headlesscites}
```

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notes,ibidtracker=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\newrobustcmd*{\headlessvolcite}{\volcitecmd\headlesscite}
\newrobustcmd*{\headlessvolcites}{\multivolcitecmd\headlesscites}
\begin{document}
\headlesscite[50]{knuth:ct}.

\headlessvolcite{1}[50]{knuth:ct}.

\citereset

\headlesscites[50]{knuth:ct}[100]{aristotle:rhetoric}.

\headlessvolcites{1}[50]{knuth:ct}{2}[100]{aristotle:rhetoric}.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Note: I think there is a bug in the `\headlesscites` macro. In some situations a spurious comma appears before the `title`. When I get a moment, I'll see if I can track it down and submit a bug report.

Comment: Too slow to beat our volcite specialist! (+1)

Comment: @gusbrs, You got the other one ;). It's nice to share :).

Comment: That must have been because you were distracted here.  ;)   But I did get to know `\volcitecmd`, as I had never really looked at how `\volcite` works.